# Call a secured micro-service from a unsecured micro-service in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, razorpay

I am integrating *Razorpay-webhook* to my **spring-boot application**. I have a requirement to store the payment data in my db and after storing the data send an email to admin. There is a module to send email which is secured using JWT token.

Now the problem is Razorpay needs a unsecured (public) API to trigger the API whenever some event occurs on razorpay server. I provided that API but from this API I need to call email-module which is secured to send the email to admin.

Any Idea how to resolve such type of requirement?

Comment: Is the JWT used to secure the email module just forwarded from the unsecured microservice? Or does the unsecured microservice have dedicated credentials to call the email module?

Comment: The unsecured microservice does not requires any credentials it can be accessed without any credentials (It is a public API).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a problem where your current system doen't support this new requirement.

You intruducing a new requirment now where you want the email microservice to accept unauthenticated users.

The best way to do is to design the email service without controllers and trigger messaging, the caller/sender will be required to be authenticatd or not.

Becuase you have limitaion I assume, you can create a new endpoint in the email service and allow the specific url to go through in Security Config.